# I want to move couple of databases from different computers to a single server. Using SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, cloud

I want to move a couple of databases from multiple computers to the server/cloud. SQL Server 2008/2012 are being used. How do I do it?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: This is way too vague. I'm going to vote to close, but you should read the following Microsoft article on SQL migration to Azure. It should help you get started enough to learn the right questions to ask. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

Comment: LOL not an even an hour since this was posted and the OP has deleted their account.